# Spring boot junit and Eclemma setup?

Tags: junit, spring-boot, eclemma

I have a project that creates a bean library and is built upon spring boot. In the latest spring tools suite (eclipse), I have a set of junit test cases that stands up a spring boot server and tests those beans. All tests are passing. I heard about the EclEmma eclipse plugin so I installed it. I left the defaults and just ran 'Coverage As' > 'JUnit Test' just like I can successfully run 'Run As' > 'JUnit Test', but the coverage is failing with

```
IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

I checked the classpath and it matches the successful JUnit runas because it's the same run as configuration. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example (e.g. on GitHub) that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: Or at least show full stack trace.